# Wkhtmltopdf unable to generate PDF .Net Core Api

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, wkhtmltopdf

I have tried to generate PDF from HTML template using wkhtmltopdf on .NET Core 5 web API, but it keeps returning the error

> “wkhtmltopdf” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
> System.Exception
> at Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html)
> at Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore.GeneratePdf.GetPDF(String html)

I downloaded the Rotativa folder that contains .dll, I also set the properties to Always for Copy.

Here is my code

```
var HTML =@"<!DOCTYPE HTML> <HTML><h2></h2></HTML>"
var pdf =  _generatePdf.GetPDF("html");

var pdfStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Ok. Will do that now.

Comment: Also possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375168/how-to-install-and-run-wkhtmltopdf-on-mac-osx-10-7-3-for-use-in-a-php-applicatio) can be useful.

Comment: I have installed wkhtmltopdf locally but I still get *"cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified"*